# Two way to batch insert and the performance is same or not?

Tags: mysql, batch-insert

About performance of batch insert.
1.

```
insert goods(...) values(...)
insert goods_price(goods_id, level, price) values(...)
insert goods_price(goods_id, level, price) values(...)
insert goods_price(goods_id, level, price) values(...)

insert goods(...) values(...)
insert goods_price(goods_id, level, price) values(...)
insert goods_price(goods_id, level, price) values(...)
insert goods_price(goods_id, level, price) values(...)
...
```

2.

```
insert goods(...) values(...)
insert goods(...) values(...)
...
insert goods_price(goods_id, level, price) values(...)
insert goods_price(goods_id, level, price) values(...)
insert goods_price(goods_id, level, price) values(...)
insert goods_price(goods_id, level, price) values(...)
insert goods_price(goods_id, level, price) values(...)
insert goods_price(goods_id, level, price) values(...)
```

About performance above two way is same or not same? Which way is more friendly to mysql?

Answer (score 0):

With your sample the performance are pratically the same 
for better performance you should use a real bacth insert like this

```
insert goods(...) values(v1, v2, v3...), (v1, v2, v3...), (v1, v2, v3...), ...
insert goods_price(goods_id, level, price) values(p1, p2,p3, ...), (p1, p2,p3, ...), (p1, p2,p3, ...), ...
```

In this sample the number of insert parsing is minor respect your sample..

Comment: You are right. But even use jdbcTemplate's batchUpdate still insert one by one. Not to mention I used Spring data jpa.